# Getting simple Java to work

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
    /* For loop to count 50 days */
    for (int n = 1; n <= 50; n++) {

        int solve = 0;
        solve = solve++;  
        item_1.removeDailyDemand();

        if ( n % 5 == 0){


        }
        if (solve == 5){

            item_1.isReOrderPoint();
        }

        System.out.print(n + "\t");
        System.out.println (item_1.getQuantityInStock() + "\t");
```

Been playing around for ages, very new to Java. I just want it to increment "solve" as it does "n" whilst running the for loop.

Been trying most the day and no results!

Thanks

Comment: change `solve = solve++;  ` to `solve++;`

Comment: just use `solve ++;` without the `solve = ` assignment.

Comment: As a start, `solve = solve++` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You are setting solve to zero in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
/* For loop to count 50 days */
for (int n = 1; n <= 50; n++) {
    int solve = 0;
    solve = solve++;
```

By:

```
/* For loop to count 50 days */
int solve = 0;       
for (int n = 1; n <= 50; n++) {
    solve++;
```

In each iteration you reset you `solve` variable to 0.
And `solve = solve++` is useless because first you copy the solve variable then you increment it. The same as `solve++`

Comment: Don't forget to declare solve outside the `for` scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the solve to zero every time inside the loop:

```
/* For loop to count 50 days */
int solve = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= 50; n++) {
    solve += 1;  
    item_1.removeDailyDemand();

    // same as your previous code
}
```

Or on similar lines you could use:

```
/* For loop to count 50 days */
int solve = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= 50; n++, solve++) {
```

Comment: It's not working, it's still displaying the message on every "n" occurrence ` int solve = 0;
        /* For loop to count 50 days */
        for (int n = 1; n <= 50; n++) {
            
            solve++;
            item_1.removeDailyDemand();
           
            if ( solve == 1);{
           
            System.out.println("Order Made");
            
            }
       
Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the whole thing (modified code).